# Different background linear gradients plus background image php loops on desktop

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So I created this php loop that has a white background opacity on mobile. However on desktop I want to take that away. Whats setting me back is that the background image for the div is dynamic based on wordpress image uploads. I've tried just making a transparent rgba in css but that removes the background image because in css is needs the bg url which doesn't work.

How can I remove the linear gradient on desktop while keeping it so the images are looping through dynamically?

End result is to have that linear gradient on images on tablets and below. Then on desktop the gradient is removed but applies on hover only.

```
      <?php $fun_loop = new WP_Query('cat=4'); 

      if ($fun_loop->have_posts()):
      while($fun_loop->have_posts()) : $fun_loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>'); ">
        </div>

      <?php endwhile; 
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You can remove the `if ($fun_loop->have_posts())`. If that method returns a falsy value, the while loop won't run either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CSS variable inside the loop that you can easily change later:

```
<?php $fun_loop = new WP_Query('cat=4'); 

      if ($fun_loop->have_posts()):
      while($fun_loop->have_posts()) : $fun_loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="img" style="background: var(--l,linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5))), url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>'); ">
        </div>

      <?php endwhile; 
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Then later

```
@media (max-width:800px) {
    .img {
       --l:linear-gradient(transparent,transparent);
    }
    .img:hover {
       --l:initial;
    }
}
```

Example

```css
.img {
  height: 400px;
  height:400px;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
  .img {
    --l: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  }
  .img:hover {
    --l: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img" style="background-image: var(--l,linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5))), url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800);"></div>
```

Another idea is to play with backgorund-size:

```css
.img {
  height: 400px;
  height:400px;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
  .img {
    background-size:0 0,cover;
  }
  .img:hover {
    background-size:100% 100%,cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800);"></div>
```